# How can a spurious interrupt be unhandled?

Tags: interrupt-handling

I'm struggling to understand the notion of an "Unhandled" spurious interrupt. From my understanding a spurious interrupt occurs when the interrupt line was asserted, but when the PIC goes back to check for the interrupt source, it's no longer asserted. This is likely caused by noise on the interrupt line.

The PIC will then tell the CPU "there's an interrupt, but [warning] it was spurious". By this point, whatever process is handling the interrupt will either (1) run the entire ISR, or will (2) realize it's spurious and do nothing. Both of those cases, in my opinion, constitute "handling" the interrupt. Conversely, if (2) is considered unhandled, I don't see anything wrong with an unhandled spurious interrupt. In fact, it's a good thing.

Am I off base on my understanding of spurious interrupts? I really don't understand how an interrupt can possibly be unhandled.